# How to retrieve a specific object store in IBM Filenet Deployment Manager?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-p8-fdm

I'm working with Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 in my current project. I wanna export classes, property templates, folder hierarchy and other assets from specific Filenet object store (there are three object stores on server) via Filenet Deployment Manager. When i'm try to retrieve object store data, there are all existing object stores are retrieved. How can i retrieve only specific object store via Filenet Deployment Manager? How should i config my environment for it?

Answer (score 2):

When you "Retrieve Data for Object Store Half Map" you are given a choice of the "Source For Object Store Data".[image: Source For Object Store Data]

If you choose "Deploy Data Set File" you will be able to get data from a single OS.

What I do is create a "Security" document.  It is a record with all the security information I will need for FDM on a content-less document object within my desired OS.
I then create a Export Manifest, adding that record with no Include Options.
Export that document.
Then run the Retrieval for OS, Security, Service, and Connection Points.

You may want to familiarize yourself with the [FDM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.common.deploy.doc/deploy_mgr_getting_started.htm) instructions.

Comment: When i "Retrieve Data for Object Store Half Map" i'm given a choice of the retrieval mode https://monosnap.com/file/GRf8GKS0cWSCYh4QjXPI1sItoUxLLV

Comment: Yes.  If you want to merge with your last export, choose Merge... if you want a clean one (probably what you want) choose the other option.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a mapping and load the object store, it creates a xml file which will have list of objectstores. Try modifying the xml and see if it works.

PS: I have not tried this solution.

Regards,
Manju